# Oracle Connection close issue with oracle 12c

Tags: java-8, oracle12c

I am using java 1.8 and oracle 12c versions in my application. As part of this I have below code to close the statement.

```
protected static void close(Statement p_stmt) 
                          throws DAOException 
    {

        if (p_stmt != null) {
            try {
                p_stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                m_logger.error("Error closing statement", sqle);
                throw new DAOException("Error closing statement", sqle);
            }
        }
    }
```

When this method executes, I am facing the below error but it is not happening consistently.

```
    Error closing statement
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.needLine(PhysicalConnection.java:4220)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.closeOrCache(OracleStatement.java:1431)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.close(OracleStatement.java:1410)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.close(OracleStatementWrapper.java:102)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.close(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:82)
```

Could I get some help to figure out the root cause of this issue?

My calling code is:

```
finally
    {
        // do not close the connection here
        close(result);
        close(stmt);
    }
```

Please let me know for more information

Comment: To help you we need some other informations: show us how are you managing connections, how are you calling the close method...

Comment: edited my question with calling code

Comment: Which java version are you using? If java >=1.7 why you are not using try-with-resources statement so you don't have to manually handle this stuff?

Comment: I am using java 1.8 as I specified in the subject and in finally block I am closing the statement

Comment: was your problem solved ? Share complete code

Answer (score 0):

Use try-with-resource statement instead of manually closing statement, resultset and connection like that:

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionURL);
     PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setxxx();
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
       <your code to process results>
   }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```